# User should be able to see username email in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I want to login on web application with the same credentials which I have with ios app. But I have forgotten the username and email. Is there any way to use the same credentials in web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're logged in into the app it means you're also probably logged in to your OpenID provider.

So, open a browser app (e.g. Chrome) and browse to these:

- https://www.google.com
- https://www.facebook.com
- https://openid.stackexchange.com

Hopefully, you'll be logged in to one of those, and can see the email being used.

Comment: This is Not working

Comment: @viveknuna you remember what OpenID provider  you're using in the app?

Comment: I don't know that, how can I know?

Comment: @viveknuna I'm afraid you can't, so only a change in the app can help any further. Still, i believe this answer might be useful for others, so leaving it around. Good luck!

Comment: These are the only three options for logging in on the app so it *has* to be one of these

Comment: @Cai not always, e.g. I'm logged in on web with my sock to SE using Stack Exchange OpenID, yet in https://openid.stackexchange.com/ I'm not logged in. So not sure how this all works. (hence using "probably" and "hopefully".)

Comment: Hmm, fair enough, guess I'm not sure how it all works either :)